# c# .NET 6.0 Determine the generic type used for a Func<T> when all you have is the base object

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say we have a Method that takes a regular object as a parameter. I need to test if the object is a Func, invoke it and retrieve the return value but the generic type could be anything and I can't have a huge long list of possibilities:

```
    public static object? Process(object o, out Type? type)
    {
        type = null;
        if (o is Action action) action();
        else if (o is int i) { type = typeof(long); return (long)i * (long)i; }
        else if (o is double d) { type = typeof(float); return (float)(d - (long)d); }
        else if (o is Func<int> funcint) { type = typeof(int); return funcint(); }
        else if (o is Func<string> funcstr) { type = typeof(string); return funcstr(); }
        else if (o is Func<object> funcobj) { type = typeof(object); return funcobj(); }
        // ...
        // ...
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: `if (o is Delgate d) return Process(d.DynamicInvoke(), out type);`

Comment: Do you need to know the base type that the func should return, or the actual type that was returned? `d.Method.ReturnType` is probably easier than bothering with generics.

Comment: Yes, the Method.ReturnType is exactly what I was after, thanks. Never used the Delegate class before. Learning every day I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the parameter type via reflection and then cast the `Func` to a `Delegate

```
Type t = o.GetType();
if (t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Func<>)
 && t.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1)
{
    type = t.GetGenericArguments()[0]; 
    return ((Delegate)o).DynamicInvoke(); 
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you. I didn't know you could do a blanket typeof(Whatever<>) like that.